# How to take 2 digits number in string and convert it to int

Tags: java, string, int, digits, converters

```
String code = "U 12 24";
int s = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(code.charAt(2)));
System.out.println(s);
```

that would be print 1,
however, i want to try print [12](/questions/tagged/12)  or i mean i want take 2 digits number, but i can't do it because the only way i know is just take one digit number.
how if i want take [12](/questions/tagged/12) and convert to [int](/questions/tagged/int)

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? What about using `substring`?

Comment: not yet, because i dot know , where i try to read

Comment: thanks before for the reference

Comment: You can Google "Javadoc" and look at the documentation. You can also use your IDE which can auto-complete for you. It's often a good thing to use this to discover the API of a given class.

Comment: anyway, how abou if i want to try take numbers that random , could be 3 digits or 4 digits but in a regular pattern

Comment: If you want to go anywhere with programming you have to like thinking and looking for the answer yourself, and I think it's the best answer we can give you.

Answer (score 0):

```
int s = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(code.substring(2, 4)));
```

If you want to get all digits in a given string, you have to tokenize the string by space and parse every chunk into a number.

Comment: how about try take random digits of number as example,

`String code = "U 1234 12";`,

and i try to take 2 numbers that separated by space, in condition i don't know how digits there are

Comment: String n= line.replaceAll("[A-z]\\s||\\s\\d+$","");
  System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(n));